# Ant Design Tree shaking with CRA

Tags: reactjs, antd, babel-loader, ant-design-pro, tree-shaking

is there any way to do "tree shaking" of Antd with React 16.13 (CRA)
i tried this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import
in package.json

```
"plugins": [
  ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true}, "antd"]
]
```

but after build all build files are with the same size. Should I expect anything else? Any advice about three shakings of Antd. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add those 3 lines into `.babelrc` instead of `package.json`

And you might want to replace `moment.js` from `antd` with `dayjs` to reduce more bundle size.